# How to detect canvas object going off canvas?

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I am trying to remove object(s) from an array when that object goes off the canvas. I saw this code work for another game, but it won't work for mine. Instead, it removes objects too early from the array and doesn't remove them at the right time. Also, the canvas is the full size of the users screen. Thanks.

The code I've tried:

```
while (bubbleDataIndex.val < bubbleData.length) {
        if (bubbleData[bubbleDataIndex.val].x > canvasWidth) {
            bubbleData.splice(bubbleDataIndex.val, 1);
        } 
        else {
            bubbleDataIndex.val += 1;
            console.log(bubbleDataIndex.val);
        }
    }
```

Full code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;

var canvasLeft = (canvasWidth - canvasWidth);

var bubbleData = generateBubbles();
var bubbleDataIndex = {
  val: 0
};
var possibleBubbleIndex = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

var currentX;
var currentY;

function generateBubbles() {
  var generatedBubbleData = []; //Array that bubbleData gets it's values from

  var bubbleCount = 0;

  var bubbleX = 0;
  var bubbleY = 0;

  function yCalc() { //Generates each circles "y" value
    var currentY;
    var mathRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    if (mathRandom < 21) {
      bubbleY = 600;
    }

    if (mathRandom < 41 && mathRandom > 20) {
      bubbleY = 500;
    }

    if (mathRandom < 61 && mathRandom > 40) {
      bubbleY = 400;
    }

    if (mathRandom < 81 && mathRandom > 60) {
      bubbleY = 300;
    }

    if (mathRandom < 101 && mathRandom > 80) {
      bubbleY = 200;
    }

    return currentY;
  }

  var mathRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);

  function xCalc() { //Generates each circles "x" value
    var currentX;
    if (mathRandom < 26) {
      bubbleX = Math.random() * 250;
    }

    if (mathRandom < 51 && mathRandom > 25) {
      bubbleX = Math.random() * 350;
    }

    if (mathRandom < 76 && mathRandom > 50) {
      bubbleX = Math.random() * 400;
    }

    if (mathRandom > 75) {
      bubbleX = Math.random() * 450;
    }
    return currentX;
  }

  while (bubbleCount < 25) { //Stops generating "x" and "y" values if there are 25 circles
    currentX = xCalc();
    currentY = yCalc();


    generatedBubbleData.push({ //Adding "x" and "y" values to the generatedBubbleData array
      x: bubbleX,
      y: bubbleY
    });

    if (bubbleCount <= 25) {
      bubbleCount++;
      mathRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
      xCalc();
      yCalc();
    }
  }
  return generatedBubbleData;
}

generateBubbles();

function draw() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth; // Sets canvas width
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight; // +mheight, with keeping good drawing quality
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.beginPath();
  bubbleData.forEach(function(bubbleDataItem) { //Draws each circle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(bubbleDataItem.x, bubbleDataItem.y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  })
}

draw();

function update(deltaTime) {
  if (!deltaTime) return;


  bubbleData.forEach(function(b) {

  });
}

/*while(bubbleDataIndex < bubbleData.length){

    if(bubbleData[bubbleDataIndex].x > canvasWidth + 20) {
        console.log("removed");
    }

    else {
        bubbleDataIndex++;
    }

    if(bubbleData.length < 25) {

    }
}*/
//ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false; //Makes images clear


function gameLoop(timestamp) { //Always updates position of circles, etc.
  let lastTime = 0;
  let deltaTime = timestamp - lastTime;
  lastTime = timestamp;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);

  bubbleData.forEach(function(bblData) {
    bblData.x += 10;
    bblData.y -= 1;
  })

  while (bubbleDataIndex.val < bubbleData.length) {
    if (bubbleData[bubbleDataIndex.val].x > canvasWidth) {
      bubbleData.splice(bubbleDataIndex.val, 1);
    } else {
      bubbleDataIndex.val += 1;
      console.log(bubbleDataIndex.val);
    }
  }
  
  update(deltaTime);
  draw();

  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

gameLoop();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding / substracting their width when comparing their x coordinate?

Comment: But they don't even delete when they are way past the edge of the canvas. I used this code from the website http://nano.tips/fullcode/. It worked for their game and the index it was increasing by each time cycles through, unlike mine.

Comment: Oh, i think I see where the problem is, `bubbleDataIndex.val` is not reset to 0 before the deleteing loop happens.

Comment: How do I reset it to 0? The website I got this code from doesn't have any code setting it to 0, yet it always loops through 0 to the highest value.

Comment: Right before `while (bubbleDataIndex.val < bubbleData.length)` call `bubbleDataIndex.val = 0`

Comment: This loops through 0 - 24, but it deletes the circles too early. What can I do then? I did put `if (bubbleData[bubbleDataIndex.val].x > canvasWidth`.

Comment: Are they deleted about 20-ish pixels too early? If so, thats their radius ( arcs are drawn from center as opposed to rectangles that are drawn from top left ) and you should include that in the comparison.

Comment: They are deleted hundreds of pixels too early, basically when they first appear. (Also, when this is solved, can you tell me how to add more circles if there are not enough with my current code?) thanks.

Comment: Your canvasWidth might not be updated then. Basically your code copied it at some state, then the canvas resized and its decynced. Just add a `canvasWidth = canvas.width` somewhere in either `draw` or `update` or `gameLoop`. To add more circles just `push` an object with `x` and `y` property to `generatedBubbleData`.

Comment: In `draw`, I have I set the width and height of the canvas with: `canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;`. Should I also make `canvasWidth` = `window.innerWidth`?

Comment: Yes, unless you plan to change the canvas size to something else. I'd set it to `canvas.width`. Just do it after you set the canvases size.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a little confused. So in my update function, I should set `canvasWidth` to `canvas.width`? And how do I set it AFTER my canvas size? (Also sorry for asking late)

Comment: The point is that `canvasWidth` should reflect the size of your canvas. You should set it where you are sure that it wont change before using it. Some places it works are: right after you set it ( in draw function ), right before you use it ( in update right before the off-canvas check ) or just update it constantly ( also, in update ). For example: `... canvasWidth = canvas.width; bubbleDataIndex.val = 0; while (bubbleDataIndex.val < bubbleData.length) ...`

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Thanks so much for answering all my questions!

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
function checkParticleOutOfWorld(object) {

leftOfObject = object.pos.x - object.radius
rightOfObject = object.pos.x + object.radius
topOfObject = object.pos.y - object.radius
bottomOfObject = object.pos.y + object.radius

outOfWorld = false

if (rightOfObject < 0 ||
    leftOfObject > canvas.width ||
    topOfObject > canvas.height ||
    bottomOfObject < 0) {

    outOfWorld = true
}

return outOfWorld


}
```